# Get POST request body as JSON of array as root node in flask-restful

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, argparse, flask-restful

Using `flask-restful` I'm trying to capture a JSON array passed into the body of a POST request, but can't seem to find it using the `RequestParser`, any ideas?

Currently my code looks like this:

```py
# api.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from resources import CustomRange
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(CustomRange, '/customrange/<start>/<end>')

app.run()

# resources.py
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()

parser.add_argument('data', action="append")
#parser.add_argument('data', type=int, location="json")
#parser.add_argument('data', type=int, location="form")
#parser.add_argument('data', location="json")
#parser.add_argument('data', location="json", action="append")
#parser.add_argument('data', type=list)
#parser.add_argument('data', type=list, location="json")
#parser.add_argument('data', type=list, location="form")
## None of the above variants seem to capture it

class CustomRange(Resource):
    def post(self, start: int, end: int):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        return args  # Always {'data': None}
```

I tried a simple example of passing the following into the POST body:

> [1, 2, 3]

But no dice. Even tried without `parser.add_argument`.

Here's the full test request that I'm using:

```sh
curl --location --request POST '127.0.0.1:5000/customrange/1/100' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '[1, 2, 3]'
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample request?

Comment: Sure, I've edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `reqparse` will handle only JSON objects as body ([source](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/blob/a2cf3a33992297110fd73742c3fbfbd7f819e5fb/flask_restful/reqparse.py#L194): will fail on any other object except dict and MultiDict), and not any other type. You'll have to grab the `request` object directly for your needs.

```py
from flask import request
from flask_restful import Resource

class CustomRange(Resource):
    def post(self, start: int, end: int):
        args = request.json
        # rest of your code
```